# What is the difference between these types of initialization?

Tags: c++, variables, constructor, initialization, declaration

In c++ I can create and initialize variables in several ways:

```
int x = 0;
int x(0);
int x = int(0);
int x = int(); // same as zero
```

but for example when declaring non-primitive data types like these, there is some kind of error.

```
string s = "";
string s("");
string s = string("");
string s = string(); // gives an error
```

What are the differences between these types of initialization and why does the last type works for int and not for string?

Comment: What error do you get for the `string s = string();` line of code?

Comment: The last line is redundant. string s; will invoke the default constructor. Doing that will invoke operator= and call the default constructor

Comment: Semi-related: [Great doc page on the many different initialization options available to you](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization).

Comment: Only error I can see in that code is `s` is reused, and I think you know that. Still, make sure you removed the other `s`s in the same scope.

Comment: Cannot recommend enough watching [CppCon 2018: Nicolai Josuttis “The Nightmare of Initialization in C++”](https://youtu.be/7DTlWPgX6zs).

Comment: I want to know how to initialize for example vector after using it. In Java I can use `vector = new Vector<String>();` is there anything similar in C++ ?

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> v;` gives you initialized empty vector which you can use..., e.g. `v.push_back("foo");`.

Comment: @OmidCompSCI -- `string s = string();` does not use the assignment operator (`operator=`). It uses the copy constructor. Yes, that `=` doesn't mean assignment.

Comment: `string s = string();` is correct (if you had the usual furniture), perhaps you made a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are functionally equivalent.
Here is nice page with details https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization

```
int x(0); // direct initialization

// These three are copy initialization with copy elision
int x = 0;
int x = int(0);
int x = int();

/// not initialization!!! declaration of function
int x();
```

For string situation is similar, although there you also choose different constructors based on what arguments you give during initialization.

Comment: I can initialize like this `string s = string();` and that gives no error, but when I write `cout << s << endl;` after it, the error looks like this - `error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

Comment: @K2osha try adding `#include <string>` to the top of the program